# GCP Private DNS Zone not taking effect on GKE pods

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, vpc, google-cloud-dns

I have a private Kubernetes cluster. The nodes of the cluster reside on a VPC.
On that VPC I attach a private DNS zone.
If I add a node to the VPC the DNS records, defined at the private DNS zone, they would be resolved by using an utility like nslookup.
If I spin up a pod on the Kubernetes Cluster and try to do `nslookup` it will not take effect.

```
Server:     10.0.48.10
Address:    10.0.48.10#53

** server can't find xxx.xxxx: NXDOMAIN
```

By using a private DNS zone attached to a VPC:

- I can resolve the records on a Compute Engine on that VPC.
- I cannot resolve the records on a GKE Pod on a Compute Engine on that VPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cloud-dns#overview) Using Cloud DNS for GKE I suggest taking a look at DNS scope, Requirements and Restriction. If your setup meets this information then from the same page you can check the “Pods unable to resolve DNS lookup” to perform some troubleshooting steps.

Comment: In that case I don't want to use Cloud DNS as a Kubernetes DNS provider. I want Kubernetes to resolve the internal dns entries without extra configuration just like it resolves the gcs and pubsub endpoint's dns without going through the internet.

Comment: Ok understood your answer